# Trouble creating a C string in Xcode

Tags: objective-c

I'm sure I'm making a stupid mistake, but I'm having trouble declaring a C string in in one of my .m files. I keep getting a failing error that just says **"Expected Identifier"**. Here's what I'm trying to do.

```
@interface myClass () {
    const char myText[6];
}
@end

@implementation
-(instancetype) init
{
    myText = ['M', 'y', ' ', 'T', 'e', 'x', 't'];
}
@end
```

And I keep getting this error when I try to build. C is clearly not my strong suit. I tried taking the 6 out of the brackets. I tried taking out the brackets all together. I tried making myText a pointer. I tried a bunch of variations on this. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This is a very hard question:  **Which line** is identified when you get the error message?

Comment: Please read the string tag-wiki: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/string/info (and refrain from tagging objective-c c)

Comment: Even after you fix that problem, there's so much wrong with that code that you won't get it to compile. This is a computer language. You have to obey the rules; you can't just write anything you like.

Comment: @HotLicks I'm getting the error on the myText = [...] line. My understanding was that a C string was essentially an array of characters, so I thought I should be able to initialize it like an array. I'm getting that that might not be the whole story.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read the [Objective-C Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH1-SW1).

If you're looking to get a `const char *`, you can obtain one from an `NSString` object.

```
- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        myText = [@"myText" UTF8String];
    }
    return self;
}
```

It's also worth noting that your interface won't compile as it currently stands. Try this:

```
@interface myClass : NSObject {
    const char *myText;
}
@end
```

Plain old data types typically aren't used in Objective-C. A better interface would use `NSString` and properties, while namespacing the class using a three letter prefix:

```
@interface ABCMyClass : NSObject 
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *myText;
@end

@implementation ABCMyClass

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _myText = @"myText";
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should share what you're trying to do, as there are generally better patterns than arrays of C `char`.

But if you're determined to use arrays of characters (and an unterminated one at that), I have a couple of observations on your initial attempt.

1. You've defined a buffer of six characters, but actually have seven characters.
2. You've defined a `const` buffer, which means you theoretically cannot update it. If you want to define a buffer that you'll update at a later point, remove the `const`:

   ```
   char text[7];
   ```

   Then you can populate that `char` array:

   ```
   text[0] = 'M';
   text[1] = 'M';
   text[2] = ' ';
   text[3] = 't';
   text[4] = 'e';
   text[5] = 'x';
   text[6] = 't';
   ```
3. I'm not sure if you wanted a unterminated array of characters, or not. If you wanted to use this array of characters as a C string, you'd also have to add a `'\0'` (making it eight characters, BTW).
4. When specifying an array of characters, you'd use curly braces, not square braces. For example if this was a local variable (which, because it's local we can use `const`), you might do:

   ```
   const char text[] = {'M', 'y', ' ', 'T', 'e', 'x', 't'};
   ```

   or

   ```
   const char text[] = {'M', 'y', ' ', 'T', 'e', 'x', 't', `\0`};
   ```
5. If you want to marry the predefined array of `char` with the `{...}` syntax, you'd use the `memcpy` (or if `\0` terminated, `strcpy`).

But again, if you're doing this in Objective-C, there are invariably better constructs than using an array of `char`. So, I'd suggest stepping back from the details of the C `char` array, and describe what broader problem you're trying to solve. There might be much better, more contemporary solutions.